# javascript not counting properly

Tags: javascript, qml

So I have a timer pretty much, but it doesnt count seconds, it just counts up but not in the same speed as a normal second. The application works just fine, but as i said, it counts but it doesnt count in real seconds. So question is how to change the speed. I'm also adding hundreth of a second to this.

```
 Timer {
        id:ticker
        interval: 100; running: false; repeat: true;
        onTriggered: point.countIn()
    }
```

Display:

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    id : display
    width : 320 ; height: 280
    color: "#fff"

    function countIn()
    {
        if (seconds == 59)
        {
            seconds = 0;
            countOut();
        }
        else
            seconds++;
    }
    function reset()
    {
        seconds = 0;
    }

    property int seconds

    signal countOut
    property int pointSize : 80

    function formatOutput()
    {
        if (seconds < 10)
            return '0' + seconds
        else
            return seconds
    }


    Text {
            text: formatOutput()
            font.pointSize: pointSize; font.bold: true
            font.family: "Courier"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, the `window.setInterval()` and `window.setTimeout()` functions are rarely called at the exact times specified. You would be better served to check the actual time in every call to your function, as this will give you the actual system time:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var hours = currentdate.getHours();
var minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Couldnt quite get it to work with this.. But thank you very much. Will look into it abit later when I have some more time! :)

Comment: Nvm, fixed it!! Thanks again for the helP!

Comment: Usually the timer is precise enough for a clock like this, I am not sure if you are aware of this obvious bug, but your interval is set to 100ms and not 1000ms!? I mean in the question, I was just writing the comment here because this is the accepted answer.